# Using sql query to print the result in a serialized format

Tags: sql

I have a database table like this:

```
C1      C2       C3
---------------------

81      1        10
81      2        20
81      3        30
82      1        40
82      2        50
82      3        60
```

Note that it has no primary key.

I want to run a query which prints C1 and the various occurrences of C3 values with it. It basically gives me the output in a serialised format. I mean something like this :

```
81 10 20 30
82 40 50 60
```

The one approach I can think of is using a `rownum` but am not sure if that;s the way to go about it. Is there a better way for doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query will depend on DBMS you use.

In MySQL, you can use `group_concat` function:

```
select c1, group_concat(c3 separator ' ')
from t
group by c1;
```